# R: Date conversion to use in SQL script

Tags: sql, r, date, date-conversion

Everyone, I can't figure this one out after 5 hours of trying and searching here at work.

I have an R script running a SQL script. I used the package (infuser) to  fill in pre-selected fields (start) and (stop) in my SQL script.

```
library(infuser)
SAPF1query <- infuse("SELECT TOP (1000) [PKID]
                ,[Equipment]
                ,[Order]
                ,[ActStartDate]
                ,[ActFinDate]
                ,[ActStartTime]
                ,[ActFinTime]
                FROM [sapData].[dbo].[SAP_IW_47]
                where Equipment IN ({{Feeder}}) 
                and OrdCat = 'ZWAR'
                and AcTyAct like '%TUT'

                and ActStartDate BETWEEN ({{start}}) AND ({{stop}})

                ", Feeder = WTGs, start = startdate, stop = stopdate)
```

I am infusing these items: Feeder = WTGs, start = startdate, stop = enddate

My startdate and eddates look like this.

```
startdate <-'2018-08-01'  #enter START-dates for report by month
enddate   <-'2018-08-31'  #enter END-dates for report by month
      SD <- as.Date(startdate, tz="UTC")
      ED <- as.Date(enddate, tz="UTC")
```

I have tried both vectors for start and end to infuse into my SQL script, with no avail. I keep getting errors that the SQL can not recognize the start and end dates.

I have tried different version of as.POSIX, format.Date, but can not get it.

My date vector looks like this when I print, "2018-08-01".

I need my date to be in a SQL script type date ike this: '2018-08-01'

With this format 'YYYY-MM-DD' I can infuse into my R/SQL script to filter my SQL query.

Thanks Your help so far but here is now my SQL error. I will try to make sure my 64bit version is correct and updated. Still a little new here and apologize for mistakes.

EDIT 1 :

Thanks Bulat. Your suggestion worked, but I get this error now.

```
  Error in executeQuery(conn, query, verbose, ...) : 
  22003 248 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The conversion of 
  the 
  nvarchar value '3000000001' overflowed an int column. 
  [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT TOP (1000) [PKID]
            ,[Equipment]
            ,[Order]
            ,[ActStartDate]
            ,[ActFinDate]
            ,[ActStartTime]
            ,[ActFinTime]
            FROM [sapData].[dbo].[SAP_IW_47]

            where Equipment IN (84010,84039,84029,84031,84022,84032,84038,84025,84017,84014,84027,84011,84015,84044,84034,84041,84035,84040,84037,84013,84042,84043,84007,84004,84002,84036,84030,84026,84016,84020,84012,84019,84023,84024,84018,84028,84033,84021,84008,84003,84005,84006,84009) 
            and OrdCat = 'ZWAR'
            and AcTyAct like '%TUT'

            and ActStartDate BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31' 
            '
```

EDIT: 2 fixed mySQL error.

I have fixed my problem with my error codes i was getting. This happens because in the database / table the [Equipment] column is stored as character and not a integer as I normally would expect.

So I needed to change my "WTGs" variable, which was a numeric verctor, to a quoted character vector.

I did this by quoting the single WTG items with '' or "". I had to look at the "shQuote" function which is part of the base package. For sure you can achieve this with the "paste" functions only as well but i find the shQuote more straight forward.

My SQL statement needs to look something like this"**** WHERE [Equipment] IN ('8001', '8002', '8003')

I used the code below in R and include it before generating the "SAPF1query" statement.

```
WTGs <- paste0(shQuote(WTGs, type = 'sh'), collapse = ",")
```

Comment: What SQL access are you using? If you are using the `DBI` package, a more robust method is with named parameters, such as `SELECT ... WHERE ActStartDate BETWEEN ? and ? ...`, then `DBI::dbBind(res, list(...))`. It's a bit more robust than string interpolation, meaning it is not subject to as many errors or an inadvertent [sql-injection attack](https://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: I have the RSQLite package installed

Comment: `res <- dbSendQuery(con, "select * from mtcars where cyl > :cyl"); dbBind(res, list(cyl=5)); dbFetch(res)` is a hasty example of binding variables.

Comment: You said you're using the `RSQLite` package, but your error is clearly using `odbc` connecting to SQL Server. Perhaps the problem is that you think you're connecting to a local *file* but in fact you are connecting to a real *database* somewhere? ;-) The number `3000000001` is an int64, so is not compatible with R without the `bit64` package (and even then there are some compatibility issues). Try installing `bit64`, updating `odbc` and `DBI`, and see if you still get the error.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not obvious which of the columns is the `BIGINT` that is triggering the issue, but if I had to guess it would be `[PKID]`. Perhaps you can do `cast([PKID] as nvarchar(16)) as [PKID]` or `cast([PKID] as float) as [PKID]` and try it again.

Comment: Thanks r2evans for your help. I will try this weekend sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You query should have something like this in the `WHERE` clause:

`and ActStartDate BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31'`

To achieve this you need to use quotes instead of brackets in your template:

`and ActStartDate BETWEEN '{{start}}' AND '{{stop}}'`

Comment: Thanks  I will try.